# Find node recursively in xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<TestSuite name="TestSuite1">
  <TestCase name="TestCase1" UID="1" State="1" DataSourceId="1">
    <TestModule name="Recording1" State="Checked" UID="1">
    </TestModule>
    <TestCase name="TestCase3" UID="bde575e2-74dd-4b5b-9d92-c12cc7e6777d" State="Checked" DataSourceId="" />
  </TestCase>
  <TestCase name="TestCase2" UID="06a4df3b-f072-4f70-a5c3-f0f2ea95654c" State="Checked" DataSourceId="" />
  <TestModule name="ds" State="Checked" UID="16b175a7-b286-484d-ba9a-2a5c9f8dd0fc" />
  <TestModule name="hh" State="Checked" UID="581f5d85-a777-483b-9b5d-ae2830302878" />
</TestSuite>

XmlNode rootNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/TestSuite");
        string s = "16b175a7-b286-484d-ba9a-2a5c9f8dd0fc";
        XmlNode l_objXmlNode = null;
        foreach (XmlNode node in rootNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            l_objXmlNode = ProcesNode(node, s);
            if (l_objXmlNode != null)
                break;
        }

    private static XmlNode ProcesNode(XmlNode node, string l_selectedNodeUID)
    {
        XmlNode l_objXmlNode = null;
        if (!node.HasChildNodes
            || ((node.ChildNodes.Count == 1) && (node.FirstChild is System.Xml.XmlText)))
        {
            if (node.Attributes["UID"] != null && node.Attributes["UID"].Value == l_selectedNodeUID)
            {
                l_objXmlNode = node;
                return l_objXmlNode;    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (child.Attributes["UID"] != null && child.Attributes["UID"].Value == l_selectedNodeUID)
                {
                    l_objXmlNode = child;
                    break;               
                }
                else
                {
                    return ProcesNode(child, l_selectedNodeUID);
                }
            }
        }

        return l_objXmlNode;
    }'
```

I have to find deepest child node from xml file having UID="value" for that i have written above recursive code but l_objXmlNode always giving me null value.I have to find deepest child node from xml file having UID="value" for that i have written above recursive code but l_objXmlNode always giving me null value.

Comment: Why not LINQ for XML? If I understand, you want to find "all" values for UID attribute. Right?

Comment: That right How should i code for Linq to Xml

Comment: One more thing, string s = "29239699-6dbc-4c38-aaef-bb5546258f83"; there is no UID with this value which will give you NULL

Comment: i have corrected string s value but still is giving null

Comment: As said @A3006 use LINQ to XML , but I didn't understand meaning of "deepest child node", looking to your XML I can suppose ,that you can find     a set of nodes, and they all will have same deepness, isn't it ?

Comment: @John Is it possible that there are more than one element with matching `UID` attribute value and you need to get only *the deepest*? If this is the case you need to explain and give example of what you mean exactly by *the deepest*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath expression to find element with `UID` attribute equals certain value, anywhere in the XML document :

```
....
string s = "16b175a7-b286-484d-ba9a-2a5c9f8dd0fc";
XmlNode l_objXmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//*[@UID='{0}']", s));
```

Or using LINQ-to-XML :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("path to your XML file");
string s = "16b175a7-b286-484d-ba9a-2a5c9f8dd0fc";
XElement l_objXmlNode = doc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(o => (string)o.Attribute("UID") == s);
```

Comment: this will always select only one element.

Comment: How to check if node has UID tag

Comment: @John you didn't answer is UID value unique in your XML or not ?

Comment: @John I believe you are asking this because you are getting ORNSTAI (obejct Ref....) error. For that in the LINQ to XML use (string)nodes.Attribute("UID") instead of .value which should solve your problem. If you are using C#6 you can opt for .? operator to check for NULL

Comment: If UID is unique, above code by @har07 makes more sense than the one I have written below.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
public static void SearchNodes()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\Test\\Test2.xml");

            var v = from nodes in doc.Descendants("TestCase")
                    where nodes.Attribute("UID").Value == "06a4df3b-f072-4f70-a5c3-f0f2ea95654c"
                    select nodes;

            foreach (var item in v)
            {
                Console.Write(item);    
            }

        }
```

You will get following output

```
<TestCase name="TestCase2" UID="06a4df3b-f072-4f70-a5c3-f0f2ea95654c" State="Che
cked" DataSourceId="" />
```

You can pass the expected value as parameter to SearchNodes function.

Comment: @A306 how to get all TestModule nodes  from XmlDocument

Comment: Just remove the where clause and replace TestCase by TestModule and you will get all TestModule nodes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/linq/topics for further information